# Get file from Azure DevOps Repo Using REST API in Powershell Script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an Azure repo where I'm trying to get my appsettings.json file from the repo from their GET ITEM rest call here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

On DevOps UI, if I navigate to my file, the url is something like:
_git/MYREPO?path=%2FSOMETHING%2FWeb%2Fappsettings.json&version=GBdevelop

appsettings.json' could not be found in the repository 'MYREPO' at the
version specified by ''

My powershell is this:

```
$appSettingsPath = "%2FSOMETHING%2FWeb%2Fappsettings.json"
$branchVersion = "develop"
$repoQueryURL = "https://" + $account + 
        "/DefaultCollection/" + $projectName + "/_apis/git/repositories/MYID/" +
        "items?path=path=$appSettingsPath&versionDescriptor.version=$branchVersion&api-version=5.0"
Write-Host $repoQueryURL
$repoListResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $repoQueryURL -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
```

No matter what I do, it can't seem to find this file that's clearly available (and navigable to in the DevOps Repo UI).

Any help where I'm going wrong?

Comment: How's your issue going?

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL. It has double path - `path=path=`. Update to

```
$repoQueryURL = "https://" + $account + 
        "/DefaultCollection/" + $projectName + "/_apis/git/repositories/MYID/" +
        "items?path=$appSettingsPath&versionDescriptor.version=$branchVersion&api-version=5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `scopePath=/SOMETHING/Web/appsettings.json` to see how's the result.